# Field name with -- threw an error in neo4j (example Age--years)

Tags: neo4j

I had a field name Age--years in a product Node and i ran a query

```
MATCH (a:Product)
RETURN max(a.Age--years)
```

but the query didn't run and threw an error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable years not defined (line 2, column 19 (offset: 36))
"RETURN max(a.Age--years)"
```

- Neo4j version: 3.4.3
- Operating system: Arch Linux
- API/Driver: Cypher and Python driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` character is normally used as the subtraction (or negation) operator. To escape such special characters in a name (for a variable, property key, label, or relationship type), quote the name using the backtick (`) character.

For example:

```
MATCH (a:Product)
RETURN max(a.`Age--years`)
```